# Using SQL in Kibana Dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

In Kibana **Canvas**, users can create metrics and data tables using (Elasticsearch) SQL.

How can users get the same metrics and data tables as created in Kibana Canvas, in Kibana **Dashboard** using (Elasticsearch) SQL?